# Factoring out REST-POST activity to a manager

Tags: java, android, database

I want to factor out the `AsyncTask` to a `Manager`. I thought to make it a singleton, but then I cannot use generics as the object to serialize to JSON and send (e.g. `PostManager<T>`).

How can this be refactored?

```
public class RestPostActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener {

...
    public static String POST(String url, Person person) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("name", person.getName());
            jsonObject.accumulate("country", person.getCountry());
            jsonObject.accumulate("twitter", person.getTwitter());

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();

            // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin
            // Jackson Lib
            // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the
            // content
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnPost:
            if (!validate())
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
            new HttpAsyncTask()
                    .execute("http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet");
            break;
        }

    }

    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            person = new Person();
            person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
            person.setCountry(etCountry.getText().toString());
            person.setTwitter(etTwitter.getText().toString());

            return POST(urls[0], person);
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    private boolean validate() {
        if (etName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else if (etCountry.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else if (etTwitter.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is separate the two concerns you have in the POST method.

The POST method should have a different name (since `POST` does not match Java conventions), and the signature should be something like:

```
public static String httpPost(String url, JSONObject data) {
    ....
}
```

And that method should handle the server communication.

You should have a second method, perhaps Person.toJSON() that converts the Person to a JSONObject.

I know I have used a different capitalization for `httpPost()` vs. `toJSON()`. For some reason, it makes sense to me since JSONObject is capitalized that way. Strict conformance to code-style guidelines suggests the method should be called `toJson()`

Once you have separated the concerns, the `httpPost(...)` method should be completely reusable.

If you want to be smart, create an interface `JSONConvertible` like:

```
public interface JSONConvertible {
    public JSONObject toJSON();
}
```

Then, you can have the stand-alone class (with the embedded httpPost method):

```
public class HttpPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private static final String httpPost(String url, JSONObject value) {
        .....
    }

    private final JSONObject toPost;

    public HttpAsyncTask (JSONConvertible convertible) {
        this(convertible.toJSON());
    }

    public HttpPostAsyncTask(JSONObject json) {
        this.toPost = json;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return POST(urls[0], topost);
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Then, make `Person` implement `JSONConvertible` ....

and you can simply do:

```
HttpPostAsyncTask atask = new HttpPostAsync(person);

atask.execute(url)
```

Comment: thanks. How would you generalize "GET" in the same manner? you would create `FromJsonParseable fromJson (Objext obj)` ?

Comment: I would probably do something similar, yes. As the data comes back, jave a custom method that interprets the JSON data back in to the right Java Object.

Answer (score 0):

There are three types to do that.

1. Use AsyncTask with Listener. [Check the example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234924/having-trouble-with-async-task-and-flow-of-program/22235712#22235712)
2. Use AsyncHttpHandler [Here](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/).
3. Combination of type 1 & 2